# Python: Boolean List to Binary String

Tags: python, list, binary, boolean

What's the fastest way to convert a list of booleans into a binary string in python?

e.g. boolList2BinString([True, True, False]) = '0b110'.

Also, how would I convert that binary string into the binary literal?  Would this take more time than just converting from the boolean list to the binary literal immediatley?  How would one do this?

e.g. boolList2Bin([True, True, False]) = 0b110.

Thanks!

Comment: An extension module written in C -- pre-allocating the space for the string and doing reference comparisons with `Py_True` -- is probably fastest. /s Seriously though, how serious is the "fastest" requirement? Did you add that just because or have you tried something and it was too slow (if so, please add details!).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regarding your first question, you can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)* and a [conditional expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394809/2555451):

```
>>> def boolList2BinString(lst):
...     return '0b' + ''.join(['1' if x else '0' for x in lst])
...
>>> boolList2BinString([True, True, False])
'0b110'
>>>
```

---

Regarding your second, you cannot "convert that binary string into the binary literal". As their name suggests, [literals](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) must be *literally typed out*:

```
>>> x = 0b110
>>>
```

Perhaps you meant that you want the quotes removed from the output?  If so, use [`print`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

```
>>> def boolList2BinString(lst):
...     return '0b' + ''.join(['1' if x else '0' for x in lst])
...
>>> boolList2BinString([True, True, False])
'0b110'
>>> print(boolList2BinString([True, True, False]))
0b110
>>>
```

---

***Note:** I purposefully chose to use a list comprehension with `str.join` instead of a generator expression because the former is [generally faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/2555451).

Comment: Remove the brackets.  `join` can handle generators, so you do not need to create a `list` first.

Comment: Instead of the `if`/`else` you can use `'01'[x]` because bools can be used as indexes.

Comment: this is the most efficient solution there is(at least out of the posted solutions) by a good margin +1

Comment: @Alfe - You are correct that you do not _need_ a list with `str.join`.  But the link I gave in my answer shows that it is generally faster to use one.  Also, if you use [`timeit.timeit`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit), you will see that the conditional expression is slightly faster than `'01'[x]`.

Comment: Whoa.  My bad :(  I ignored the __Note__ below the answer, sorry.  And now that I want to revoke my downvote I only can so if the answer has changed.  May I humbly ask you for doing a minor edit of it just for allowing me to?

Comment: Much obliged, and again my apologies for being so hasty :-/

Answer (score 6):

Convert the list to a decent binary (will be a long int):

```
number = reduce(lambda a, b: (a<<1) + int(b), [ True, True, False ])
```

And then, if you really need a "binary string", as you put it, use

```
bin(number)
```

to generate that string.

EDIT

You also can use this code:

```
number = sum(int(bit) << position
             for (position, bit) in
             enumerate(reversed([True, True, False])))
```

The mechanism behind it is the same as before.

Comment: In Python 3+ `reduce` us moved to [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) module.

Answer (score 4):

```
data = [True, True, False]
print bin(int("".join(str(int(item)) for item in data), 2))
# 0b110
```

Answer (score 2):

```
values = [True,False,False,True]
bin(sum(int(v)*2**i for i,v in enumerate(values[::-1]) ))
```

actually

```
In [7]: %timeit bin(sum(int(v)*2**i for i,v in enumerate(values[::-1]) ))
10000 loops, best of 3: 108 us per loop

In [8]: %timeit '0b' + ''.join(['1' if x else '0' for x in values])
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.25 us per loop

In [9]: %timeit bin(int("".join(str(int(item)) for item in values), 2))
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.5 us per loop

In [10]: %timeit bin(reduce(lambda a, b: (a<<1) + int(b), values))
10000 loops, best of 3: 31.3 us per loop
```

my solution is the slowest :( ...

Comment: fixed ... minor error :P assumming LSB is on RIGHT in bool list at least

Comment: But given your tests and results, your answer is (among) the best :)

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [True, False, True]
''.join(map(str, map(int, L))) # '101'.
```

Comment: Just timed it, this solution is three times slower than the accepted one. While the difference might often not matter, the question was specifically about the fastest way to do this, so here it does matter.